# unable to debug through my attached project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have added two projects to my solution in Visual Studio 2012 and when I try to debug these projects, I am able to debug one of the project and unable to debug the other.

What may be the reason and how to solve this?

Comment: if you are not able to debug projects,firstly try locating thier pdb's .if they  are c/c++ projects enable native code debugging in visual studio

Comment: Its is C# project only

Comment: What type of projects do you have? (Console, WinForms, WPF, MVC, etc.) And do you have the pdb files in the bin folder?

Comment: Rebuild project in debug mode, you must get pdb and you will be able to debug

Comment: @NULL:I use MVC project

Comment: I have Pdb files, but unable to debug

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your settings and how you started the solution, you might have got a solution that has one project marked as Startup Project, that means when you press F5 only that project is started.

Here are some things that you can try:

1. Check the Startup Project under the Solution Properties. If it's set to Single startup project you might need to select the one you want to debug, or choose Multiple startup projects.
2. Try starting the project directly by right clicking on it then selecting Debug->Start new instance.
3. Alternatively you can try attaching the Debugger to the webserver that's running the project. On the menu Debug->Attach to Process
4. Check the Web Tab of the Project Settings. Try setting the Start Action to either Current Page or Specific Page. Also under Debuggers ASP.NET should be checked.